# What does !d command

Tags: bash, terminal

Could someone explain to me what `!d` command does?

It seems to recall an old command (`du -sh` for me) but I have no idea how this command is chosen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`!` is event designator in bash. You can read more about it here https://alexbaranowski.github.io/bash-bushido-book/#event-designator-word-designator-modifiers  (this is my own book about bash and tricks).

`!STRING` will invoke the last command starting with STRING.

**Edit: Excerpt from the link/book:**

To invoke the last command that starts with a given string, use the event designator with a string so that the command looks like `!<string>`. **Example below:**

```
[Alex@SpaceShip cat1]$ whoami
Alex
[Alex@SpaceShip cat1]$ who
Alex :0 2018-04-20 09:37 (:0)
...
[Alex@SpaceShip cat1]$ !who
who
Alex :0 2018-04-20 09:37 (:0)
...
[Alex@SpaceShip cat1]$ !whoa
whoami
Alex
```

Comment: There was comment that I should copy information from the link. It is reasonable, because well it might (I won't delete repo) change in the future. So I edited post.

Answer (score 7):

According to the manual [9.3.1 Event Designators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Event-Designators.html):

> **!string** 
> Refer to the most recent command preceding the current position in the history list starting with string.